# leetcode 560. Subarray Sum Equals K

Tags: c

I found a weird thing on Leetcode 560.Subarray Sum Equals K

Here is my code, which compiled by gcc

```
#define HASH_LEN 10000

int hashTable[HASH_LEN][2] = {0};

inline int hash_push(int value)
{
    int hashIdx, tempHashIdx;

    tempHashIdx = hashIdx = (value > 0) ? (value%HASH_LEN) : ((-1*value)%HASH_LEN);
    while( hashTable[hashIdx][1] > 0 )
    {
        if( hashTable[hashIdx][0] == value ) 
        {
            hashTable[hashIdx][1]++;
            return 1;
        }

        hashIdx = (hashIdx+1)%HASH_LEN;
        if(tempHashIdx == hashIdx) return -1;
    }
    hashTable[hashIdx][0] = value;
    hashTable[hashIdx][1] = 1;

    return 0;
}

inline int hash_find(int value)
{
    int hashIdx, tempHashIdx;

    tempHashIdx = hashIdx = (value > 0) ? (value%HASH_LEN) : ((-1*value)%HASH_LEN);

    while( hashTable[hashIdx][1] > 0 )
    {
        if( hashTable[hashIdx][0] == value ) return hashTable[hashIdx][1];

        hashIdx = (hashIdx+1)%HASH_LEN;
        if(tempHashIdx == hashIdx) return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int subarraySum(int* nums, int numsSize, int k){

    int i, j,  ans = 0, sum = 0, hashIdx;


    hash_push(0);


    for(i = 0; i < numsSize ; i++)
    {
        sum += nums[i];
        ans += hash_find(sum-k);
        hash_push(sum);

    }

    return ans;
}
```

it will get wrong answer at the test case:
[1,2,3]
3

But I using the "Run Code" function to execute the same test case, I got a "Accepted".

Can anyone explain this?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

OK... I got it..
I should re-initialize the global varible hashTable every time at the function begining.